# Unit testing an Angular service with Router dependency: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am trying to test a simple service that uses the Router as a dependency and writes all routes to a history array. I am more or less using the service described on [this tutorial](https://blog.hackages.io/our-solution-to-get-a-previous-route-with-angular-5-601c16621cf0).

I have tried all the solutions I could find in the Angular.io documentation. I have tried several solutions here on StackOverflow. I even tried adding routes to mock components, declaring them, and adding those to `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes()`. For some reason, `router` is `undefined` in all cases.

```
describe('Route State service', () => {
    let routeStateService: RouteStateService;
    let router: Router;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule],
            providers: [RouteStateService]
        });

        router = TestBed.get(Router);
        routeStateService = TestBed.get(RouteStateService);
        router.initialNavigation();
    });

    describe('should add each route to history', () => {
        router.navigate(['/test']);
        expect(routeStateService.history.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });

});
```

The error is fairly straight forward, but for some reason I am unable to get "router" to be defined by normal means. What am I missing?

Comment: can you please what you have tried?

Comment: Per the post, I tried several implementations I saw on the documentation and StackOverflow. I also tried adding mock components and routes to `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes()`. What I have not tried was making the `beforeEach()` async, since I am not using any components or rendering, so I do not need to await compiling the component.

Comment: Your inner describe() function should be an `it()`, not a `describe()`. beforeEach() is run before each test, but you have no test at all. Only an empty suite inside an empty suite.

Comment: Wow. D'oh. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `it` in place of `describe`

```
it('should add each route to history', () => {
        router.navigate(['/test']);
        expect(routeStateService.history.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
```

and also use fakeAsync as the routing is asynchronous

```
it('navigate to "/test" redirects you to /test', fakeAsync(() => { 
  router.navigate(['/test']); 
  tick(); 
  expect(location.path()).toBe('/test'); 
}));
```

you can have some reference here https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/routing/